# iOS 9.2.1 Unable to see setting bundle in device settings

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, ios9, ios9.2

I have a project which uses Settings.bundle including root.plist containing a list of key value pairs I want to register with user defaults. Until recently, these values were visible and editable from the device's "Settings" App. Now I can't see anything when tapping on my app in settings - the details panel is empty.

Its working fine in iOS8 and works on iOS 9.2 simulator. But not on device which has iOS 9.2.1.

I google it and find same problem with no answer yet :(

- [Apple Forum](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/9853)
- [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27340116/2439156)

But seems not work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i think this is the bug in iOS 9.2.1. I perform the following steps and it showing my app settings in Device setting app.

1. Force quit the my app & settings app.
2. Relaunched the my app & settings app.

Now its showing the app settings in settings app.

Hope Apple fixed it in next iOS updates.